# How to write quick sort on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting

I'm continue trying to write a alrorithms on Node.js like on the book Algorithms, 4th ed. Sedgewick, Wayne. There all the examples written on Java.

I have this quick sort module:

```
"use strict";

const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = (function () {

  function _partition(array, lo, hi) {
    let i = lo;
    let j = hi + 1;
    let v = array[lo];

    while (true) {
      while (_less(array[++i], v)) {
        if (i === hi) {
          break;
        }
      }
      while (_less(v, array[--j])) {
        if (j === lo) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (i >= j) {
        break;
      }
      _exch(array, i, j);
    }
    _exch(array, lo, j);
    return j;
  }

  function sort(array) {
    _sort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }

  function _sort(array, lo, hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) {
      return null;
    }

    let j = _partition(array, lo, hi);

    _sort(array, lo, j - 1);
    _sort(array, j + 1, hi);
  }

  function _less(array, i, min) {
    return array[i] < array[min];
  }

  function _exch(array, i, min) {
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[min];
    array[min] = temp;
  }

  return {
    sort: sort
  };

})();
```

I use mocha and chai for testing with this function:

```
function isSorted(array) {
  for(let i = 1, size = array.length; i < size; i++) {
    if (array[i] < array[i-1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

and quick sort not working. 
I need the same implementation as in book, but on js.

You can see original implementation here: [quick sort in java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/Quick.java.html)

Comment: You need the same implementation as on the book? Or you need a working quicksort algorithm in javascript?

Comment: So can't you debug what exactly is not working and see what step fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `_less` uses **indexes** as arguments:

```
  function _less(array, i, min) {
    return array[i] < array[min];
```

but you call it with array **elements values**:

```
 let v = array[lo];
 while (_less(array[++i], v)
```

(and omit first argument `array` - is it legal in JS?)

Comment: No need _less function at all. Just compare to elements of array. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

That implementation is ugly.

Sorry, I won't be able to help you answer a course question, but here is the beauty of a functionally recursive version of quicksort. Never, ever, use the above in javascript.

**In ES6**

A functionally recursive quicksort.

```
const quicksort = ([head, ...tail]) => head === undefined ? [] : 
  [...quicksort([...tail.filter(a => a <= head)]), head, ...quicksort([...tail.filter(a => a > head)])];
```

**Usage**

```
console.log(quicksort([1,3,1,0,6,8,9,12,15,22,54, 111,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,-1]));
```

Comment: I'ts not quite beauty

Comment: Why not? It's one line. How would you write a functionally recursive quicksort in javascript?

Comment: Can`t run it on Node.js

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Use the harmony flag

Answer (score 0):

---

> *Simplest (most readable) quick sort function I've been able to come up with.*

---

#### Quick Sort (Readability Was The Focus)

---

```js
let quickSort = (items = [], left = [], right = []) => {
    if (items.length <= 1) return items
    
    let pivot = items.pop()
    let pushToSide = item => (item < pivot ? left : right).push(item)
    
    items.forEach(pushToSide)

    return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)]
}
```

> *Note: Two other ways to write the same logic above are as follows*

---

#### for loop instead of foreach

---

```js
let quickSort = (arr = [], left = [], right = []) => {
    if (arr.length <= 1) return arr;
    
    let pivot = arr.pop();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        (arr[i] < pivot ? left : right).push(arr[i]);
    
    return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)];
}
```

> _ Quicksort using anonymous callback function within items.forEach instead of variable passed callback_

---

#### Anonymous `ForEach` Callback

---

```js
let quickSort = (items = [], left = [], right = []) => {
    if (items.length <= 1) return items;
    
    let pivot = items.pop();

    items.forEach(item => (item < pivot? left : right).push(item)) 
    
    return [...quickSort(left), pivot, ...quickSort(right)];
}
```

---

#### Short list of other sorts created in js/node.js and references to some useful links

---

```js
let sort = {
  quick: (items = [], left = [], right = []) => {
    if (items.length <= 1) return items

    let pivot = items.pop()
    let pushToSide = item => (item < pivot ? left : right).push(item)

    items.forEach(pushToSide)

    return [...sort.quick(left), pivot,...sort.quick(right)]
  },


  bubble: (items = []) => {
    for (let passover = 0; passover < items.length; passover++)
    {
      for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
      {
        if (items[index] > items[index + 1])
        {
          let temporary = items[index]
          items[index] = items[index + 1]
          items[index + 1] = temporary
        }
      }
    }

    return items;
  },

  select: (items = []) => {
    for (let passes = 0; passes < items.length; passes++)
    {
      let min = passes 

      for (let i = passes; i < items.length; i++)
      {
        if (items[i] < items[min]) {
          min = i
        }
      }

      if (min !== passes) {
        let temporary = items[passes]
        items[passes] = items[min]
        items[min] = temporary
      }
    }

    return items
  },

  insert: (items = []) => {
    for (let i = 1; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      let index = i-1
      let temporary = items[i]

      while (index >= 0 && items[index] > temporary)
      {
        items[index + 1] = items[index]

        index--
      }

      items[index + 1] = temporary
    }
    
    return items
  },

}

console.log('quick: ', sort.quick([0,43,3,2,3,4]))
console.log("select: ", sort.select([0,43,3,2,3,4]))
console.log("insert: ", sort.insert([0,43,3,2,3,4]))
console.log("bubble: ", sort.bubble([0,43,3,2,3,4]))
```

```html
<ul>
<li>sort.quick O(n log n) avgerage time complexity</li>
<li>sort.bubble O(n^2) average time complexity</li>
<li>sort.insert O(n^2) average time complexity</li>
<li>sort.select O(n^2) average time complexity</li>
<li><a href="https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms">Watch how different sorting algorithms compare in real time</a></li>
<li>
<a href="https://bigocheatsheet.com">Time Complexity/Space Complexity cheat sheet</a></li>
</ul>
```